# Is there a way to make an android application to communicate to a service installed in a different android phone?

Tags: android, android-service

I am into a project for my college purpose. For that purpose i have to create 2 applications (1 ACTIVITY app and another SERVICE app) which will be installed in 2 different mobiles. I want to create communication b/w those 2 apps, i.e when i request data from the activity app the service app in other mobile should respond and reply the data i require...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is only possible if you pass and receive the data through some form of communication channel, like Bluetooh or WiFi.

The best idea I feel would be to have a server that acts as a middleman. One device sends data to the server, and the server sends the data to the other device via [Push Notifications](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html). Or you could use the server as a middleman to open a socket directly between both the devices, but this has the disadvantage of not being able to resend messages easily if the first send fails.